# How to define www and .com as the canonical versions of the domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Trying to figure out how the DNS should be configured for the domains example.com example.net so that:

1. www.example.com is the canonical version of the domain (example.com should also still work)
2. example.net and www.example.net "redirect" to www.example.com

Comment: DNS does not do HTTP redirects. You need a web server for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately DNS doesn’t handle redirects, as such *(not in a way that's well supported, anyway)*.

The redirect needs to be done at your server, at a HTTP level. This means that your web application/server software should handle the redirect, after the DNS resolution has taken place and the user has arrived at your server.

You could set up all your domain DNS records to point to your web server, and then configure your web server or web application to redirect in the desired way.

[Beyond Ink](http://www.beyondink.com/howtos/301-redirect.php) lists some of the most common ways to do redirects, depending on your server type.

However, most Domain Providers offer the option to configure this for you as part of their control panel. Your domain’s `@`, `A` or `CNAME` records will need to point to the domain provider’s servers for them to be able to manage this redirection for you.

Comment: A `CNAME` record wouldn't be valid at the zone apex.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that DNS can not redirect. you need a http server to do that. But you can still use DNS URL forward service offered by most of the Domain Name Registrars.

You can forward www.example.net to www.example.com

You need to goto the Domain Registrar DNS control panel for domain example.net and search for options that says Domain Forwarder - enter the domain where you want to "redirect" the queries and you are done.

You can use masked or unmasked forwarding.

More information here -- https://www.domain.com/domains/tools.bml

Thanks